# Error -4304 when calling a Java stored procedure in DB2

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2

Here's a sample Java class that I wrote

```
public class Sleeper  {

    public static void Sleep(int seconds){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

and I wish to call this as a stored procedure this way :

```
DROP PROCEDURE DEM.SLEEPUTIL@

-- echo "ETAPE 2 DE 3 > Suppression puis instllation du JAR";
CALL SQLJ.REMOVE_JAR('DEM.SLEEPER_JAR')@
CALL SQLJ.REFRESH_CLASSES()@
CALL SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR("file:///Sleeper.jar",'DEM.SLEEPER_JAR',0)@
CALL SQLJ.REFRESH_CLASSES()@

-- echo "ETAPE 2 DE 3 > CREATION DE LA PROCEDURE ";
CREATE PROCEDURE DEM.SLEEPUTIL (IN NUM INTEGER) 
  COMMIT ON RETURN NO 
  SPECIFIC SLEEPUTIL 
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 0 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  LANGUAGE JAVA 
  PARAMETER STYLE JAVA 
  NO DBINFO 
  FENCED 
  THREADSAFE 
  NO SQL 
  PROGRAM TYPE SUB
  EXTERNAL NAME 'DEM.SLEEPER_JAR:com.desj.visa.db.procedures.Sleeper!Sleep'
```

And I'm repeatedly getting this error:

```
14:54:00  [CALL - 0 row(s), 0.032 secs]  [Error Code: -4304, SQL State: 42724]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-4304, SQLSTATE=42724, SQLERRMC=DEM.SLEEPUTIL;SLEEPUTIL;/db2/db2d095/sqllib/function/jar/DEM/SLEEPER_J, DRIVER=4.3.85
CALL DEM.SLEEPUTIL(3);
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.032/0.000 sec [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found It.

The problem was related to the Java version installed on the server.

The server has Java 1.5 and the code I deployed to was compiled in 1.6.

So I recompiled everything to 1.5 and deployed it.

Everything works fine now so you guys have a good example on how to deploy a Java stored procedure on DB2.

Cheers.

Comment: You should select this as the answer.